# NSStackView, two developers, one on 10.10 (Xcode 7), one on 10.12 (Xcode 8)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

My fellow developer and I are working on a macOS app.

- I'm running Xcode 8 on 10.12
- He's running Xcode 7 on 10.10
- Deployment target is set to 10.10

I developed the project on Xcode 8 on 10.12.

I am using an NSStackView for one section of the UI. App runs on my OS (10.12) and his OS (10.10) after I put in some version checks and "if version > x then run (code)" to address the changes made to NSStackView in 10.11.

The majority of the project (all but the xib containing the NSStackView) will open in his 10.10+Xcode 7 after I set "Opens With..." to "Xcode 7.x".

The Xib with the NSStackView, however, will not. He cannot open it. He also cannot compile the project as it complains that:

`"The document “ControllerWithStackView.xib” requires OS X 10.11 or later"`

I'm assuming that the xib contains additional information on the 10.11-enhanced NSStackView that his older OS and Xcode can't handle.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might change things such that he could continue using 10.10 and Xcode 7 while I use 10.12 and Xcode 8? For several reasons it's preferred that he keep his current OS.

My ideas:

- Don't embed the NSStackView in the xib via interface builder. Instead, create it in the controller via code
- Don't use NSStackView. While it does work for our purpose (traditional add/remove/show/hide behavior ideally tailored to the stack), I suppose I could either use an NSTableView or code something custom

Are there other options? Are there any magic settings in Xcode 8 that I could set to say "hey, this stack view should be aiming for 10.10"?

Any insights on how people approach situations like this would be very much appreciated.

Thank you,
Eric

Comment: I would create two test projects, one using your colleague's system and the other using yours. Add a stack view and some subviews to both in the same way. Compare the resulting .xib files for significant differences. Hopefully, use what you learn to tweak your project .xib to be compatible with the other system. Or, similarly, create one on his system and then open it and re-save it on yours and see what Xcode changes.